# AWS Serverless 403 forbidden API gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am trying to create a serverless Nodejs application. I deployed my app to S3 and it is running. But the URL seems to be https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxx-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod. So, whenever my app is trying to get css files or video files or even the links they are going to [URL/](http://URL/) which is perfect. But here the url is [URL/prod](http://URL/prod), it should be like [URL/prod/whichever-route-it-is](http://URL/prod/whichever-route-it-is) So, my static files are not being rendered and even the links are not working. Is there any way to re route to URL/prod or remove the prod from api endpoint?

Comment: Generally, you should serve static assets like CSS from your S3 bucket, possibly indirectly via CloudFront, not from your API. And consider using AWS SAM or serverless framework as they will make this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS API Gateway follows this pattern in the URL:

> www.example.com/my-base-path/MyStage

You must configure each part accordingly. For example, you may create a base path "prod", and stage "whichever-route-it-is" for something like:

> www.example.com/prod/whichever-route-it-is

Base Path Mappings are configured under Custom Domain Names.

Answer (score -1):

Move the folders holding your static files into a /prod/ subfolder in S3.

Or, use Cloudfront to route /css/*, /js/* or whatever static paths to the S3 bucket and skip API gateway

Or, configure API Gateway to overwrite the path for /css/*, /js/* or whatever

I prefer moving files to the subfolder, or Cloudfront solutions. This allows control over different stages of the API. For example, when you are ready to launch v2, but not completely take down v1, you would want to have prod/ and prod_v2/ available. This way, your folder structure maps to the API Gateway stages nicely.

Comment: I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/tree/master/examples/basic-starter) to deploy express app. So, the whole package is zipped and uploaded to S3. I doubt if even though I place static files separately I should probably change the links too right? I mean /home to /prod/home.

Comment: I think this link may help: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html - you should be able to formulate the correct configuration for your particular app with that information.

And yes, your assets should include the stage from with they are being requested (ie: prod)

Comment: thanks for you time. I changed the base path mappings in custom domain name and the files are now being rendered.